# x'(t)=g(t)tan(x), initial conditions solution bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $x'(t)=g(t) \tan(x)$ and for which initial conditions (if any) are the solution bounded? Sketch the solution.

I solve the differential equation: $ x(t)= \arcsin( e^{G(t)+C})$ with $ \int g(t)\, dt = G(t) + C$

If $x(0)=x_0$, then $ x_0=x(0)= \arcsin( e^{G(0)+C})$. $\iff C=\ln(\sin(x_0))-G(0)$

It becomes $ x(t)= \arcsin(e^{G(t) - G(0)} \sin(x_0))$

How should I answer the second question about boundedness of the solution?

In its domain arcsin satisfies: $ - \pi/2<\arcsin(t)<\pi/2 $. For all initial value $x_0$ it is $-1 \le \sin(x_0)\le 1$. Does anyone know what I should do for this question?

Comment: No information about $g$ ?

Comment: We don't have more infomation about g.

Answer (score 2):

the differential equation has the implicit solution $$\sin x = \sin x_0 \ exp\left({\int_0^t g(s) \, ds} \right)$$ therefor the $t$ must satisfy the constraint $$  \int_0^t g(s) \, ds  \le \ln \left(\frac1{|\sin x_0|} \right).$$

Comment: thanks, And when x_0 satisfy this condition the explicit solution is bounded? Then I can apply the arcsin on the implicit solution right? But what is when x_0 don´t satisfy the constraint, is it then always not bounded?